# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

The error is in an ASP.NET Ajax application. This is the line of JQuery UI code the error refers to:

```
Sys.Extended.UI.DropDownBehavior
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The solution was to replace `<asp:ScriptManager>` with `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>`.

Comment: Minor mistake: It is <*ajaxToolkit*:ToolkitScriptManager>, not <*asp*:ToolkitScriptManager>.

Comment: asp or ajaxToolKit: it is matter of tag prefix when you register ajax tool kit at top of page.

Comment: THANK YOU. (over a year later...)

Comment: Thanks a trillion (You saved my hours at Google)

Comment: As of version 15.1, this is no longer supported. <asp:ScriptManager> should work just fine

Comment: Well Toolk‌​itScriptManager is dropped from the ajaxtoolkit, asp:ScriptManager works but, this console error is annoying, it should be fixed. :/

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I ended up needing to use `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>` instead.

Comment: This appears to be the correct way of forming the tag based on the default tag-to-namesapce registration which happens when adding the package from NuGet.

Comment: thank you, this one works for me, why do they change tags from version to version? is very missleading

Answer (score 2):

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

use it instead of simple script manager

Answer (score 0):

First, register the assembly:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Then add the toolkitScript Manager:

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Few Days Ago,I got this same error

So I Add "**Latest AjaxToolKit.dll**" In our Solution.
You Can download in from following URL
"https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/ajaxcontroltoolkit_dll.html"

and Its Working For Me